# How to create a table with primary key using jdbc spark connector (to ignite)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I'm trying to save a spark dataframe to the ignite cache using spark connector (pyspark) like this:

```
df.write.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://<ignite ip>") \
  .option("driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver") \
  .option("primaryKeyFields", 'id') \
  .option("dbtable", "ignite") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()

# .option("createTableOptions", "primary key (id)") \
# .option("customSchema", 'id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, txt TEXT') \
```

I have an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No PRIMARY KEY defined for CREATE TABLE
```

The library org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark-2.4:2.9.0 is installed. I can't use the **ignite** format because azure databricks uses spring framework version that conflicts with the spring framework version in the org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark-2.4:2.9.0. So I'm trying to use jdbc thin client. But I can only read/append data to an existing cache.

I can't use the overwrite mode because I can't choose primary key. There is an option `primaryKeyFields` for the **ignite** format, but it doesn't work on jdbc. The jdbc `customSchema` option is ignored. The `createTableOptions` adds primary key statement after the schema parenthesis and a sql syntax error occurs.

Is there a way to determine a primary key for the jdbc spark connector?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with correct syntax that should work fine:

```
 DataFrameWriter < Row > df = resultDF
  .write()
  .format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE())
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), configPath)
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE(), "Person")
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS(), "id, city_id")
  .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS(), "template=partitioned,backups=1")
  .mode(Append);
```

Please let me know if something is wrong here.

Comment: Oh, I see that you are speaking about JDBC integration. Let me re-check it and update the question soon.

Comment: ignite format doesn't work in azure databricks due to different spring framework version, and I couldn't force it to work.

Comment: Got it. I will try to check the case with JDBC DataFrameWriter.